# android code for distancebetween() method

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DistanceBetween() two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845357/distancebetween-two-locations)

I need the code for the android method public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results) which depend on two location and get the distance between them Any help please